# searching array of numbers in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I am facing an issue in mongodb searching/matching.
If anyone could help i will be very thankful:

I have create a mongoose schema as follows:

```
    newNumbers: [
      {
        new: [Number],
      },
    ],
```

In "new" array i am storing some integers

And from the frontend i am sending 10 integers in "allNumbers" array to check if any one of the 10 integers   is present in the "new" array or not.
If present i want to return Number Found otherwise return Number Not Found

I tried the following code:

Here, allNumbers is an array of 10 integers

```
      const { allNumbers } = req.body;

      const existingNumbers = await numberModel.find({
        "newNumbers.new": { $in: [allNumbers] },
      });

      if (existingNumbers) {
        return next(
          errorHandler(
            404,
            "Number Found"
          )
        );
      }
```

The problem i am getting is that although any of the 10 integers are not present in the new array. It is returning Number Found.
But if any one of the 10 integers is not found i want to return Number Not Found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mongoose `Model.find()` method returns an array of 0 or more documents so if your query doesn't find any matches then `existingNumbers` will be an array with `array.length` = `0`.

This is not to be confused with other methods such as `Model.findOne()` where no matches would result in a `null` return value.

Your code currently checks for `if (existingNumbers)` which will always be `true` for a variable containing an array in this context.

I would recommend you check for `array.length` which will be true if greater than 0 or false if 0:

```js
const allNumbers = [1,2,3,4]
const existingNumbers = await numberModel.find({
    "newNumbers.new": { $in: allNumbers  }
});

if (existingNumbers.length) {
  //... Numbers found
  //... Return suitable response
}else{
  //... Numbers not found
  //... Return suitable response
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are saying that for my case find() method with existingNumbers.length will be a good option instead of using findOne() method right

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you want to do something with all matching results then `findOne` will only return the first matching document so you will miss some hits. The `find` method will find you all matching documents. If you use methods such as `findOne` or `findById` etc then no match will always be `null` whereas `find` will never be `null`, it will alwys be an `array` so you need to handle your `if` statements differently.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$in` with an array, Mongo checks for documents where the specified field contains any of the values in the array.

You don't need to wrap the `allNumbers` in a `[]`, it is already an array of numbers, according to your code.

```
const existingNumbers = await numberModel.find({
  "newNumbers.new": { $in: allNumbers },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. your answer is right but a silly mistake in your solution. that is the exact solution that is working for me is using findOne instead of find